# Getting results from PHP and using them with jQuery after the page load

Tags: jquery, html, load

I am looking for loading result like a number of new emails or new comments, etc. But I'd like to get the data after loading the main page. So, I want to load the main page first and then show numbers by using jQuery functions.

```
<ul>
    <li>new emails (3)</li>
    <li>new comments (12)</li>
    <li>new whatever (3)</li>
</ul>
```

I know I have to use `$(document).ready(function(){});` then run a PHP file for getting the results but I don't know how to get back the results and how to show them on my page. Could anyone help me? Or direct me to the right path.

Comment: what you required is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: before take a look to jquery probably is better to take a look to the ajax paradigm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can wrap your count in a `span` or any other tag with an `id` or `class` and update them after ajax request.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>new emails (<span id='newEmails'>3</span>)</li>
  <li>new comments (<span id='newComments'>12</span>)</li>
  <li>new whatever (<span id='newWhatever'>3</span>)</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

This script make a ajax request to `yourpage.php` and get json encoded data. It then decodes the json and update the count in your html.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'yourpage.php',            
      success: function(response){
        //parse your json data
        r = $.parseJSON(response);

        //update your html          
        var newEmails = r.emailCount;
        var newComments = r.commentCount;
        var newWhatever = r.whatever;

        $('#newEmails').html(newEmails);
        $('#newComments').html(newComments);
        $('#newWhatever').html(newWhatever);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
        //handle ajax error
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**PHP**

Get all of your count from database and store it inside array. Encode and echo the array at last.

```
<?php
 //your database operation

 $data = array();
 $data['emailCount'] = 5; // your email count from database
 $data['commentCount'] = 10; // your comments count from database
 $data['whatever'] = 15; // your whatever from database

 echo json_encode($data); //encode your data in JSON format
```

**NOTE:** You may not need to use JSON if you are confused. You can just echo the required data in your php and get it as a response. But its easier to encode and decode data with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use a ajax call using jQuery and get the values by particular intervals(eg: every 5 sec).
Example like this
 JS :

```
window.setInterval(function(){

   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "UR URL",
     success : function(){

        //Your function here

     }
   });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: if you only need to get, without loads of data, `$.get()` would be better to use, cleaner code :) Also, giving this type="GET" is not needed, its the default value

Answer (score 0):

**JS:**

`jQuery.ajax({

type: "GET",

url: "YOUR PHP FILE PATH HERE",

data: {username:'username'}, // send the data to the PHP page here like username or whatever

dataType: "json",

success: function(data)

{

var unread_emails=data.email;

var unread_comments=data.comments;

var unread_whatever=data.whatever;

jQuery('li#emails').val("New Emails "+unread_email);

jQuery('li#comments').val("New Comments "+unread_comments);

jQuery('li#whatever').val("New whatever "+unread_whatever);

},

error: function()

{

alert("Some error");

});`

**In your PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET['username']))  
{  
    **DO YOUR QUERY HERE TO GET UNREAD EMAILS, COMMENTS, WHATEVER and STORE IN VARIABLES**

    $return=array('unread_emails'=>$unread_emails, 'unread_comments'=>$unread_comments, 'unread_whatever'=>$unread_whatever);  
    echo json_encode($return);   
}
```